# Integrating this integral : $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{6(x-1)^2 - x\{x\}}{x^5} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am having a hard time finding the value of a rather peculiar integral given by:

$$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{6(x-1)^2 - x\{x\}}{x^5} dx$$

Any ways to tackle this beast in a single form have evaded me, so I split the integrals in two parts.

So I let

$$I_1 = \int_1^{\infty} \frac{6(x-1)^2}{x^5}dx$$

and

$$I_2 = \int_1^{\infty} \frac{\{x\}}{x^4} dx$$
The first one - to my surprise, was relatively easy to evaluate by a single substitution of

$$ x = \frac{1}{t}$$

The integral then evolves into the relatively easy

$$ I_1 = \int_0^1 6x(1-x)^2dx = 6 \int_0^1 (x - 2x^2 + x^3)dx = 6(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{4}) =  \frac{6}{12} = \frac{1}{2}$$

But I have no idea on how to go about evaluating this second integral

$$ I_2 = \int_1^{\infty} \frac{\{x\}}{x^4} dx$$

I think I have an idea - that would be - instead of thinking about the integral upto infinity, we consider a smaller case first - like for a smaller upper bound - say $n=4$.

I did try that idea and I obtained:

$$ I_2 = \int_1^2 \frac{x-1}{x^4} dx + \int_2^3 \frac{x-2}{x^4} dx + \int_3^4 \frac{x-3}{x^4}$$

$$I_2 = (\frac{1}{2\cdot 1^2} - \frac{1}{2\cdot 2^2} + \frac{1}{3\cdot 2^3}-\frac{1}{3\cdot 1^3}) + (\frac{1}{2\cdot 2^2} - \frac{2}{2\cdot 3^2} + \frac{2}{3\cdot 3^3} - \frac{1}{3\cdot 2^3})....$$

But I was unable to simplify this further, or extrapolate anything else from this. Please help me solve this integral. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right path for the second integral.

Let us consider the integral from $1$ to $n$, where $n$ is some natural number greater than 1.

Then after splitting $I_2$ into the intervals like you have done:

$$\ I_2 = \int_1^2\frac{x-1}{x^4}dx + \int_2^3\frac{x-2}{x^4}dx + \int_3^4 \frac{x-3}{x^4}dx + \int_4^5 \frac{x-4}{x^5}dx +..... + \int_{n-1}^n \frac{x-(n-1)}{x^4} dx$$

$$ = \left[\frac{1}{2}\cdot (\frac{1}{1^2} - \frac{1}{2^2}) - 1\cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot (\frac{1}{1^3} - \frac{2}{1^3})\right] + \left[\frac{1}{2}\cdot (\frac{1}{2^2} - \frac{1}{3^2}) -(1+1)\cdot \frac{1}{3}\cdot (\frac{1}{2^3} - \frac{1}{3^3})\right] + \left[\frac{1}{2}\cdot (\frac{1}{3^2} - \frac{1}{4^2}) -(1+1+1)\cdot \frac{1}{3}\cdot (\frac{1}{3^3} - \frac{1}{4^3})\right]+....\left[\frac{1}{2}\cdot (\frac{1}{(n-1)^2} - \frac{1}{n^2}) -(1+1+1...(n))\cdot \frac{1}{3}\cdot (\frac{1}{(n-1)^3} - \frac{1}{n^3})\right]$$

The sum for the portion multiplied by $\frac{1}{2}$ is obvious. For the second sum, take the first $1$ out of every $(1+1+1....)$, then the second $1$, and so on. We will get:

$$ = \frac{1}{2} \cdot( 1 - \frac{1}{n^2}) - \frac{1}{3} \cdot \left[(1 - \frac{1}{n^3}) + ( \frac{1}{2^3} - \frac{1}{n^3}) + (\frac{1}{3^3} - \frac{1}{n^3}) + ..... + (\frac{1}{(n-1)^3} - \frac{1}{n^3})\right]$$

$$ = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2n^3} - \frac{1}{3} \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k^3} + \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{(n-1)}{n^3}$$

Note that as $n$ tends to ${\infty}$, the terms $\frac{1}{2n^3}$ and $\frac{(n-1)}{n^3}$ go to $0$. Thus, we obtain:

$$I_2 = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\zeta(3)}{3}$$

Which makes the final integral equal to

$$ I = I_1 - I_2 = \frac{1}{2} - \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\zeta(3)}{3}\right) = \frac{\zeta(3)}{3}$$

Answer (score 3):

Recall that $\{x\} := x - \lfloor x \rfloor$. Then
$$
I_2 = \int_1^\infty \frac{x}{x^4} \, \mathrm{d}x
- \int_1^\infty \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x^4} \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
The former is trivial. For the latter, break it up into cases: for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, when $x \in [n,n+1)$, we have that $\lfloor x \rfloor = n$. Sum up across each interval of that type. Then
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x^4} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_n^{n+1} \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x^4} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n \int_n^{n+1} \frac{1}{x^4} \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
What remains is likewise trivial.

Comment: +1: Elegant....